# Use read variable in nawk command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

I need to use two variables entered by the user to able the match two files.

*`Actors.txt`*:

```
James Bond - A
The Rock - A
John Cena - B
```

*`Interests.txt`*:

```
James Bond - Shooting
John Cena - Wrestling
The Rock - Wrestling
```

So the user should enter the interest followed by the Group and then i should display the matched Names

Code :

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter Group"
read groupid *// example : A*
echo "Enter Interest"
read int *// example : Wrestling*
echo "Result :"
nawk -F "-" '/int/ {print $1}' Interests.txt | grep "$(nawk -F "-" '/groupid/ {print $1}' Actors.txt)"
```

Expected output : The Rock

Comment: So this would be something like: `nawk -F "-" -v gid="${groupid}" '($0 ~ gid) { print $1}' Actors.txt`

Comment: @kvantour Thanks for you comment . This solved my issue. Thanks again